# On the Amalgamated Product

Tags: group-theory

Let $F_2=\langle x,y\rangle$ be Free group of rank 2, and $\mathbb{Z}/2=\langle z : z^2\rangle$ be the cyclic group of order 2. Consider an injection $1\mapsto y$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $F_2$ and a surjection $1\mapsto z$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2$. Then the amalgamated product of $F_2$ with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ along $\mathbb{Z}$ is

$F_2*_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/2) = \langle x,y,z : yz^{-1}=1, z^2=1\rangle =\langle x,z : z^2=1\rangle$,

this is non-trivial group (I am not sure whether this is correct; but I have written this from a simple abstract definition of amalgamated product; please suggest if wrong).

---

In the book "Trees" by Serre, the problem is to prove that

$\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Q})*_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z}/2)=1$,

with respect to injection from $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbb{Q})$ and a surjection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/2$ (See [Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540442375), page 2 in book.)

**Question:** Why the amalgamated product in the problem of Serre is trivial? (from my computation of amalgamated product in above example, I confused with this. Please help me.) (Thanks in advance!!)

Comment: What is the injection of $\mathbb Z \to \rm{PSL}(2, \mathbb Q)$ you consider ?

Comment: This is not mentioned in the problem in the book of Serre. (I included link in question)

Comment: This follows from the fact that ${\rm PSL}(2,{\mathbb Q})$ is simple. (This is true for all fields apart from those of orders 2 and 3), and so imposing any nontrivial relation on its elements will give the trivial group.

Comment: @Derek Holt: Oh! I had known that $PSL(2,K)$ is simple (with 2 exceptions), but I never thought about the trick in your nice "one line answer". You may post it as answer.

Comment: If the injection $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow PSL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ isn't mentioned, it should be a safe assumption that it's $n\mapsto\begin{pmatrix} n & 0 \\ 0 & n \end{pmatrix}$.